# A word to define the set of the terms 'Regional', 'National', 'Global'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I'm looking for a word that defines the level of a competition, for example, a regional competition, a national competition, or global competition, an inter-school competition, or international competition etc.

Comment: Have you tried level, ambit, scope, and their synonyms?

Comment: I'm preferably looking for a noun that is unique to this subset.

Comment: I think a header like *regionality* with the options of *local*, *regional*, *national*, *global* would be understood, but I cannot find definitions to support this usage.

Comment: I would use _**tier**_ or _**level.**_

Answer (score 1):

See **scope** defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scope) as

> The extent of the area or subject matter that something deals with or to which it is relevant.

Also, there is the formal **purview**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/purview) as

> The scope of the influence or concerns of something.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases I wouldn't use *tier*, as this is already very commonly used to describe the skill bracket of competitors in most sports (e.g. "they are a tier 1 team"). I also doubt that there exists a noun specifically for this, as I haven't seen anything like that used in sports or e-sports. I find *region* used the most.

I also see *stage* used quite frequently.

Answer (score 1):

One word that is often used in reference to competition is [***league***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/league). This can imply hierarchical levels (local vs national or children vs teenagers), but also exclusive groups of competitors at the same level (one country's teams). From Collins Dictionary:

> 1. countable noun  A **league** is a group of people, clubs, or countries that have joined together for a particular purpose, or
>      because they share a common interest.
> 2. countable noun  A **league** is a group of teams that play the same sport or activity against each other.
> 3. countable noun  You use the word **league** to make comparisons between different people or things, especially in terms of their
>      quality.

This phrase is very commonly used in some sports<sup>1</sup> (American baseball comes to mind, which divides the sport both by level, e.g. Little vs Minor vs Major leagues, and also into groups of competitors, e.g. National vs American leagues), but I think would be understood in a wider competitive context.

On the other hand, if you are referring to the various *stages* of a single competition, then you might want a word like *bracket* or *round* or *stage*.

---

<sup>1</sup> From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sports_league&oldid=767980401):

> A sports league is a group of sports teams or individual athletes that compete against each other in a specific sport. At its simplest, it may be a local group of amateur athletes who form teams among themselves and compete on weekends;[1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/league) at its most complex, it can be an international professional league making large amounts of money and involving dozens of teams and thousands of players.

Answer (score 1):

**Standing** and **ranking** are used for this:

> Standing: to identify rank or status, especially with respect to social, economic, or personal position, reputation, etc. ([Dictionary.com #1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/standing))
>
> Ranking: occupying a specific rank, position, etc. (often used in combination):
> a low-ranking executive. ([Dictionary.com #3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ranking))

A competitor having regional, national, or world standing or ranking would usually be considered to be among the most notable competitors for that category. However, even a poor competitor may be ranked at some unremarkably low position in the ranks for a region, nation or the world.

To say that a competitor has regional standing or is ranked nationally would usually be taken to mean that that competitor is among the highest ranked (regionally or nationally). The same could be said for one with world standing.

Additionally, **class** is used, most often as in *world class*, and less frequently as in *national class* or *regional class*.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for "Scale" since you could also say "a competition on international scale".

Answer (score 0):

I would use **"range"** in such context.

> [**range**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/range) -  "the area or sphere in which an activity takes place"

From the Internet:

- "decisions related to energy public policies either in state or national range"
- "the tools include cellular telephones, cellular modems, beepers with regional or national range, and ..."
- "and in sports events of local or national range"
- "most of the studies were published in journals of regional or national range"

Answer (score 0):

The words *regional, national & global* in your example represent the ***territory*** in which the competition is effective (and consequently the level of the competition).

ODO:

> **[territory](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/territory)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1.3** An area in which one has certain rights or for which one has responsibility with regard to a particular type of activity.
>
> ‘The accountancy/small biz software specialist now wants to be known
>   as Best Software in the US, a territory now responsible for more than
>   half group sales.’